# How to select this dropdown with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Here is the HTML code:

```
<select id="faculty_id" name="faculty_id[]" class="form-control select-select2" multiple="" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">                                                                               
 <option value="1">Scholl Related matrial</option>
 <option value="2">English Department</option>
 <option value="3">Management  Department</option>                                          
 <option value="4">Mind Channel</option>                                            
 <option value="5">Other</option>`                                          
 <option value="6">Office Department  </option>                                 
</select>
```

I am new to selenium , currently am working on selenium web driver. Please suggest me some ways to click the drop down.
I am creating script but did not get perfect call.
Please help me to create script to click the dropdown and store the value in array.

Dropdown menu screenshot: http://prntscr.com/100j0km

Dropdown menu list: http://prntscr.com/100j1og

Comment: is it a combox when you click that field is drop down showing up ?

Comment: The example element you show here has 'style="display: none;"' meaning it is not visible. I think you are trying to interact with the wrong element.

Comment: @MS Demo is trying to another method but Still Is not working. Html Code= prnt.sc/103kh9e Script code =prnt.sc/103kjb2 Console Output = prnt.sc/103kk2g

Answer (score 1):

As your element has `style="display: none;"` it is not displayed. Looks like the Select is an hidden container to store that data that is trigger by an INPUT element. Try setting the value of input or sending keys to the input.

**Below doesnt work, because select is not interact-able**:

The Selenium WebDriver has an API for working with Selects, read [the working with Selects documentation here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_select_elements/).

For Java and your situation this would look something like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement selectElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("faculty_id")));
Select selectObject = new Select(selectElement);

selectObject.selectByIndex(1);
selectObject.selectByValue("2");
selectObject.selectByVisibleText("English Department");
```

Do not try to manual click the select and getting all the items. Use the API :)

Comment: Still Not working

Comment: @MSDemo You get a error? "Still not working" is not a very helpfull comment to assist you resolving an issue. We cannot see your screen, so you need to provide any information that might give us a clue what is going on on your side.

Comment: Probably the Select is not there yet when you try to access it, try waiting for it to be visible. Or it is in a HTML iFrame, try to switch to the frame first.

Comment: I am trying to another method but Still Is not working. Html Code= prnt.sc/103kh9e Script code =prnt.sc/103kjb2 Console Output = prnt.sc/103kk2g –

Comment: @MSDemo You get an "element is not interactable" exception. This means the element is in the DOM, but might be still hidden, or it has an overlay (e.g. loading indicator). Maybe there are multiple elements with the same ID, of which the first is hidden. Or wait until the element is clickable. But it could that the field is just disabled until you focus or do something else first in the form.

Comment: @MSDemo I added a wait to the example code, maybe it helps. Otherwise I suggest you try to read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni It has more directions to resolve the error you are getting.

Comment: Looking at your DOM, the dropdown is not a real select, the select is probably populated by a Front-End framework from the <INPUT> changes, I think just driver.findElement(input).sendKeys() might work here. Ignore the Select as it is implementation for storing the data, not the part to interact with, that is the input.

Comment: I am trying to all script but did not get the call the click event so do you have other solution , please can you suggest me

Comment: I got the solution, Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MSDemo You can answer your own question with how you solved it, maybe it will help others in the future. Also if my answer helped or my comments let me know so I can improve the answer shown here. You can also accept my answer as the answer so the system does not keep promoting your question as unanswered to other users.